AWS MWAA times out trying to connect to EKS API Server
I am trying to test out the EKSPodOperator to launch a pod from MWAA into EKS. I am getting an https timeout when the tasks tries to connect to the EKS API Server.
I can connect to the EKS API server from my local laptop so I've confirmed it publicly accessible. So it sounds more like an MWAA issue.
The security group for MWAA is set to allow all traffic on it egress rule. So I would think it could talk to anything thats publicly accessible.
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='REDACTED.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/namespaces/airflow/pods?labelSelector=dag_id%3Deks_pod_example%2Cdemo%3Dhello_world%2Ckubernetes_pod_operator%3DTrue%2Crun_id%3Dmanual__2024-06-18T132428.5113700000-b8a425de4%2Ctask_id%3Dstart_pod%2Calready_checked%21%3DTrue%2C%21airflow-worker (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1c87a07690>, 'Connection to REDACTED.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))


So I resolved this by adding an ingress rule to the EKS Cluster security group that allowed access from the MWAA security group. I was confused why this was needed if the EKS API server is publicly accessible. But then it occurred to me that the EKS server is probably being resolved internally and  never even going out to the internet. My setting on my eks cluster access is public and private. I assume it if was just public, this would not be needed. Hopefully this helps someone else.
